# Python: pandas: match row value to column name/ key's value

Tags: python, pandas

**Problem**
"How to match a row value to a column name and take that intersecting value in pandas"

**Context**
We have a pandas df like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': 'john', 'john': 1, 'mac': 10}, {'name': 'mac', 'john': 2, 'mac': 20}], columns=["name", "john", "mac"])
```

Looking like this:

```
name | john | mac
john |  1   | 10
mac  |  2   | 20
```

**Desired output**

```
name | john | mac  | value
john |  1   | 10   | 1
mac  |  2   | 20   | 20
```

In words, the column `"value"` should take the number from the corresponding column where name intersects.

So, if `name == 'john'`,  then take the value from column 'john'
So, if `name == 'mac'`, then take the value from column 'mac'

**Tried so far**
Bunch of lambdas (none successful).

**Specifications**
Python: 3.5.2
Pandas: 0.18.1

Comment: The definition of dataframe does not correspond to the table (different values)

Comment: sorry, my bad. fixed post with correct figures.

Answer (score 4):

> **Deprecation Notice**: `lookup` was [deprecated in v1.2.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.2.0.html#deprecations)

You could use [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html), which accepts the row and column labels to use:

```
In [66]: df
Out[66]: 
   name  john  mac
0  john     1   10
1   mac     2   20

In [67]: df["value"] = df.lookup(df.index, df.name)

In [68]: df
Out[68]: 
   name  john  mac  value
0  john     1   10      1
1   mac     2   20     20
```

Note that this will have problems with duplicate row labels (which could be trivially worked around by adding a reset_index).  It should be faster than calling `apply`, which can be pretty slow, but if your frames aren't too large both should work well enough.

Comment: oh well. always a shorter way to go i guess. good one, cleaner than my answer.

Comment: never used `lookup` before, this looks great

Comment: are there any speed differences for large data sets (2mln rows)? Is a lambda faster here or a lookup

Answer (score 3):

well imo lambda is the way to go, but you can make it very short such has:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': 'john', 'john': 5, 'mac': 10}, {'name': 'mac', 'john': 10, 'mac': 15}], columns=["name", "john", "mac"])
df = df.set_index('name')
df
Out[64]: 
      john  mac
name           
john     5   10
mac     10   15

df['values'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x.name], axis=1)
In[68]: df
Out[68]: 
      john  mac  values
name                   
john     5   10       5
mac     10   15      15
```

I did set the index to name for convinience but you could do it without it such has:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': 'john', 'john': 5, 'mac': 10}, {'name': 'mac', 'john': 10, 'mac': 15}], columns=["name", "john", "mac"])
df['values'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x['name']], axis=1)
df
Out[71]: 
   name  john  mac  values
0  john     5   10       5
1   mac    10   15      15
```

Comment: your second example seems the most elegant to me and did the trick. thanks!

Comment: glad it helped!