# Pandas: Matching column each value with column name and creating another columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hello i am trying to create new columns in a dataframe, existing columns one of the column values are matching  with column name. and wanted check with other column values  which is having any values or zero i tried below solution did not get my output

[Python: pandas: match row value to column name/ key's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181319/python-pandas-match-row-value-to-column-name-keys-value?rq=1)

my dataframe which is  looking like

```
loc     Var A   T   C   G
3985    T   0   0   1   0
4491    G   10  0   0   25
4492    G   0   1   0   0
5265    A   35  10  0   1
7328    G   0   0   20  1
6927    A   1   0   0   0
```

output what i wanted

```
loc     Var A   T   C   G  REF ALT
3985    T   0   0   1   0    0   1
4491    G   10  0   0   25   25  10
4492    G   0   1   0   0    0   1
5265    A   35  10  0   0    35  10
7328    G   0   0   20  1    1   20
6927    A   1   0   0   0    1   0
```

column "REF" columns match the values of "Var" and the ALT column which will search with the otherthan Var value, rest of the columns any one have value, i just wanted to match between four column(A,T, G, C) to get the other two column in dataframe

any suggestions? help

Comment: Why did you change column A for loc 5265 in your output?

Comment: @Erfan Sorry I apologize, I will edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.lookup` first to get your `REF` column. Then we create `ALT` column by getting the `max` value out of all the other values in the same row:

```
l1 = df.lookup(df.index, df['Var'])
l2 = df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(list, axis=1)

df['REF'] = l1
df['ALT'] = [max(set([x]) ^ set(y)) for x, y in zip(l1, l2)]

    loc Var   A   T   C   G  REF  ALT
0  3985   T   0   0   1   0    0    1
1  4491   G  10   0   0  25   25   10
2  4492   G   0   1   0   0    0    1
3  5265   A  35  10   0   1   35   10
4  7328   G   0   0  20   1    1   20
5  6927   A   1   0   0   0    1    0
```